# Why is xsl:value-of not working here (XML namespaces)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have the following snippet of XML from an ASP.NET Web API:

```
<DrilldownModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Models">
  <AddressInfo xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Entities.Drilldown">
    <d2p1:AddressNumber>4213</d2p1:AddressNumber>
    <d2p1:AddressUseType>RESIDENTIAL</d2p1:AddressUseType>
    <d2p1:EncryptedParcelId i:nil="true" />
    <d2p1:GisError i:nil="true" />
    <d2p1:GisErrorDetail i:nil="true" />
  </AddressInfo>
</DrilldownModel>
```

I am using the following to try and get values from the document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Models"
  xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Entities.Drilldown"
 >
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="//AddressInfo/d2p1:AddressNumber"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I don't get the value back.  If I remove, the default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Models`, I am able to retrieve the value.

Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that the default namespace applies to descendent elements without a namespace prefix too, and declaring a default namespace on `xsl:stylesheet` doesn't affect XPaths in your XSLT.

So, in your XSLT, define a namespace prefix for the default namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Models"
```

And then replace

```
    <xsl:value-of select="//AddressInfo/d2p1:AddressNumber"/>
```

with

```
    <xsl:value-of select="//m:AddressInfo/d2p1:AddressNumber"/>
```

so that you're selecting `AddressInfo` elements in the `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MY.API.Models` namespace where it resides.

Comment: Oh good grief - that was simple!!  Worked like a champ.  Thank you.